# How solve "ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead."?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, curve-fitting, data-fitting

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkmacosx import Button
top = Tk()
top.title("Jobs")
top.geometry("1000x800")

line1 = LabelFrame(top, text='')
line1.pack(expand = 'yes', fill = 'both')

n = StringVar()

categorychoosen = ttk.Combobox(line1, width = 27, textvariable = n)


# Adding combobox drop down list
categorychoosen['values'] = ('Advocate','Arts','Automation Testing','Blockchain','Business Analyst',
                             'Web Designing')
  
categorychoosen.place(x=50, y=150)
categorychoosen.current()



    name=Label(line3,text="Welcom to ... company",font =("Arial", 10))
name.place(x=0, y=0)

n1 = StringVar()
sectionchoosen = ttk.Combobox(line3, width = 27, textvariable = n1)
  
# Adding combobox drop down list
sectionchoosen['values'] = (' Computer Science', 
                          ' computer engineering',
                          ' Information Technology',
                          ' artificial intelligence',
                          ' cyber security',
                          ' computer networks',
                          ' Information Security',
                          ' Management Information Systems',
                          ' Software engineering',
                          ' data analysis',
                          ' Data Science')
  
sectionchoosen.place(x=20, y=20)
sectionchoosen.current()

def model():
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    from scipy.sparse import hstack
    from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
    from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
    from sklearn import preprocessing
    import numpy as np



    Category= ['Advocate','Arts','Automation Testing','Web Designing']
    job = categorychoosen.get()
    section = sectionchoosen.get()
    expert = expertchoosen.get()
    language = languagechoosen.get()

    # transform 
    p = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

    target= p.fit_transform(Category)
    target.shape
    wordOfjob = p.fit_transform(job)
    wordOfsection = p.fit_transform(section)
    
    #zip
    features = list(zip(wordOfjob,wordOfsection))

   # train_test_split
   x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features,target ,random_state = 42, test_size = 0.2)

   # Knn Classifier                       
   model = OneVsRestClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric= 'euclidean'  ))
   model.fit(x_train,y_train)
   prediction = model.predict(x_test)

   # Result in GUI_Lable 
   jobResult = Label(line4,text=str(prediction) ,bg='light gray')
   jobResult.place(x=0, y=80)


but= Button(line4,text="Start",bg='gray', command=model)

but.place(x=0, y=120)



top.mainloop()
```

I have a problem with the error, when I execute this code, it appears like this:`raise ValueError( ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead..`

---

note:`categorychoosen` and `sectionchoosen` and `expertchoosen`  and `languagechoosen`  its Combobox in GUI python

I searched a lot and concluded that this error is always from the line `model.fit(x_train,y_train)`, but I tried the solutions offered on the Internet, but no correction occurred to me. please help me.
Even after adding me to `target.shape`. I get the same error. The error starts when the button is pressed in the interface, i.s. when the function `def model()` is started

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full traceback of the error and the output of `target.shape` so that we can better understand your issue

Comment: i editing naw, please help me in my error. It has been going on for a long time and I have been searching for a solution to this error